# how to read files recovored by scalpel?

Tags: files, delete, file-format, data-recovery

I used scalpel to recover some deleted jpg files. Now I have files which look like this: jpg-1-21, jpg-1-22 etc... but don't know how to open them. I tried with image viewer, but it says there's no image file.

Comment: they're not working, but i find the solution. I answered myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution.
You have to use Nautilus as root. That way you can see that those are not files, they're folders and inside those folders are jpgs.

Scalpel protects folder with recovered files.